How to run a Selenium script in WSL2 Ubuntu and open Chrome on Windows?
I am running a Python Selenium script in a WSL2 Ubuntu environment. However, I want the script to control and open Chrome installed on my Windows system (not in WSL).
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

I explored using an X server to display Windows Chrome but realized that’s not what I need plus it didn't work.
I installed Chrome inside WSL along with the Chrome WebDriver. The script now works, and webpages are opening in the Chrome browser installed on WSL.
(It works fine for the below simple code snippet.)

from selenium import webdriver

# Keep Chrome browser open after program finishes
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/")

# driver.close() # Close the active tab
driver.quit() # Close the entire browser window

However, the Chrome browser installed in WSL is extremely slow.
What I really want is for Selenium to open and control the Chrome browser installed on Windows instead of the one in WSL. Is there a way to achieve this?
Any guidance, setup instructions, or examples would be greatly appreciated!
